# Best approach to implement a user survey

Tags: user-research, surveys, user-journey

We have a site where a user has to fill out series of forms including personal details for purpose of employment screening.

At the end of the process (or the user journey), we'd like to provide the user a suvery to gather feedback. Something simple, 3 questions.

Approaches we are looking at

- On the final screen, provide a form approach.
- On the final screen, provide a link to third party site like surveyMonkey.
- We have the users email address, so on completion we could send an email with a link to a survey

What is the best approach that balances high engagement without annoying the end user? Is there a better way that I've not thought of?

Answer (score 2):

Transform conventional surveys to conversations which will lead to higher engagement. Try to collect feedback naturally, gain insights and make better decisions. So go for the Form Approach. But in a more interactive way.

```
Example:
```

You go for a chat and provide a complete questionnaire where you plant the questions one by one

```
Case1:
```

You : Hey John this Marie. Thanks for the subscription. Got a moment to share your thoughts...
John: Gladly
You: What are the top reasons that made you choose us(And you provide interactive buttons with prompt words and onclick() event you set the flag for the reply)

```
Case2:
```

You: Good morning John. Got a few minutes?
John: Yes
You: Am taking feedback from everyone on our company culture...
    of the top of your head. how good is our company culture on a scale of 1 to 10 (And you provide buttons switch-case numbers for the reply)

Would suggect you not send him any links to go for a survey cause trust me people HATE IT. Try to make it interactive. Make a lot of combinations of questions ready with you with Rich Interface, buttons, checklists etc

Comment: Do you have any sources for concluding that conversational surveys lead to higher engagement or that people hate being sent 'links to go for a survey'?

Comment: @AndrewMartin

I do not have a so called "sources" for concluding that  conversational surveys lead to higher engagement or that people hate being sent 'links to go for a survey'?


However it comes from a lot of personal experiences I had with clients during product management. **Any thoughts?**

Answer (score 1):

Surveys are white noise, most people hate them and won't complete them - even if they're short.

Unless they aren't white noise.

**Stick out somehow.** Since you're being intrusive/potentially annoying already, you may as well at least be real. Take a risk and get their attention: "If you complete our survey, we will be your best friend - forever."

People need a break. A bit of levity in a an earnest survey that doesn't take itself too seriously isn't a bad way to give people a break.

Answer (score -1):

There are several methods in the Usability and User Experience (UX) research areas that have been used for capturing issues and experiences, for instance, surveys in a long-term use have been regarded as an effective way to get information about your users.

**Methodology**

As a short answer, and talking about methodology, it depends on the users' profile. You can analyze and evaluate general customers, young users, elderly users, physicians and so on. Also, you need to have in mind if you want a qualitative measurement, a quantitative measurement or both. If you have no idea what options do you have, you can start [here](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/which-ux-research-methods/). Assuming that this is a general customer experience user survey, I would recommend both methods:

1) A method for [quantitative measurement](https://www.nngroup.com/reports/how-to-conduct-eyetracking-studies/);

2) A method for [qualitative measurement](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/usability-test-checklist/);

[image]

For (1) quantitative measurements you will need to have a perception about what are the user interface errors, where are your users clicking and where are your users taking more time on the user interface. On the other hand, measuring (2) qualitative characteristics of the user interface will put on what you ask here, you will need to ask simple questions to obtain engagement that you want.

**The Answer**

You should use a tool called [hotjar](https://www.hotjar.com/) or a similar to it. With this tool, you can support the (1) quantitative measurement by using the [heatmaps](https://www.hotjar.com/heatmaps) ("eyetracking") functionality and you can solve the (2) qualitative measurement by creating small and simple [surveys](https://docs.hotjar.com/v1.0/docs/how-do-hotjar-surveys-work).

I also recommend the use of [Polls](https://docs.hotjar.com/v1.0/docs/how-do-hotjar-polls-work). Since it allows you to ask your site visitors an unlimited number of questions. You also can configure them to appear randomly.

[image]